# Custom System Dialog - Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: c++, windows, qt4, windows-mobile-6.5

i am tryng to override system dialog (System Sound), by closing that notification and showing up mine.
Questions:
1- How to Close Notifycation Dialog from the system
2-How to cacth the key (Volume Key) that initiates the notification
3-show mine
Well i have googling this issue but i cannot get any advance:
My application is Qt based.

Answer (score 0):

first of all i need a hook keyboard.
this links is what a i am tryng now:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12154/Keyboard-hooks-in-WinCE
i am studyng and adapting this article to my needs.
Second:
I need to customized the system notification (Volume Control):
I wil apply this approach.
Well i will inform the result